# KDE Restore "window menu" as text menu (as default)

Tags: debian, gui, kde5

I have only button "window menu". I don't see "text menu" if i remove button. It I see:
[image]

It i want see:
[image]

I was remove all kde & plasma files... I was create new user and he also don't "see window menu" as text.

Comment: Does `Ctrl+M` work?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon yes, it is work. Thank you. and... hotkey for it in "settings panel"?

Comment: I'm not sure If I understood correctly but try `Alt+S`. Btw, when you usually press the key `Alt` in various applications you will get an **underline** in the toolbar which means is the shortcut for the specific menu. For example, in this case with dolphin, pressing `Alt` you will see that `Settings` menu get an underline in `S` which means that the shortcut for settings is `Alt`+`S`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I mean, I need hotkeys for displaying "text menu" in another app some as "system settings", "Konsole" etc

Comment: I believe the shortcut `Ctrl+M` should apply for most of kde apps, for example `Konsole` use `Ctrl+Shift+M` (since `Ctrl+M` is usually a keybinding in the shell then the shortcut uses `Shift`). For any other non-kde app the shortcut might another one or it might not exist.